# Which CAPTCHA should i use?

Tags: asp.net, captcha

I would like to implement CAPTCHA in my website for secure registration. I have seen many CAPTCHA and RECAPTCHA solution.

I would like to know which control is highly recommended for ASP.NNET Website. For which control i should make my trust?

Please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used, and personally recommend [Recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/).

- It has nice ASP support and good documentation.
- It has a strong support community.
- It is well known and widely used in the industry.
- It does useful work while being a CAPTCHA.
- It's free.

Comment: Recaptcha is trivially easy to implement in ASP.Net, I was up and running within 10 minutes of crreating a Recaptcha account.  Definitely recommended!

Comment: It also has an audio option for blind users, if you need Section 508 compliance in the U.S.A.

Answer (score 3):

This question is rather subjective. But I'll answer it anyway.

You do know that [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/) is not only a CAPTCHA component right? There are ['meaningful' purpose](http://recaptcha.net/learnmore.html) behind it.

I've personally use it before and find it very will implemented and easy to use.

However it is not very theme-able but that's not a big issue for most usage.

There's a catch though. If you are using it in a closed environment, e.g. Intranet with no internet access, you will not be able to get it to work.

For other .NET based CAPTCHA controls, there are tons out there. Can't provide much information for you as I've not used them extensively.

Here's an 'old' but intersting article written by Jeff which you might want to read:
[An ASP.NET CAPTCHA Server Control](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000094.html)

Comment: Thanks,

But here i have question. recaptcha is used to correct digitize book while in case of captcha it's just to validate human or machine.

If we have requirement like registration form then we can use captcha because we just need to stop automation for brute force attack. Also in case of recaptcha we have strong dependancy over recaptcha webservice.

Is there any other reason for recaptcha?

Comment: Refer to jeffamaphone's answer, that are the reasons why you use ReCaptcha. Recaptcha is using human input to prevent spam as well as to help in digitizing of books. Yes, there's dependency, but it's the novelty of the idea that makes people want to use it too. If dependency is a technical constaint, then I'll say use other solution. Hope I answered your question. :P

Comment: Why would you need CAPTCHA if your application was not connected to the internet?